# Program to show a "toast" notification popup from the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, toast

I have a monitoring script that I'd like to pop up a "[toast window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632289(VS.85).aspx)" when it detects that something happens.  Is there a simple executable available that I can just run to do this?  I know it's relatively easy to write such a thing, but I'd rather just use an existing program if there's one available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GrowlNotify software has a Windows version [here](http://blog.growlforwindows.com/2009/04/new-growlnotify-command-line-script.html).

Answer (score 0):

QuickMacros is also capable of doing this but it is $40....it does however cook your breakfast as well... ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Snarl](http://snarl.fullphat.net/) out there.

Been using it for a while and it seems to be a bit more developed than Growl , last time i've checked.